# Disable Devtools in Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf component

Tags: webview2

I want to disable devtools from Webview2 component in wpf application .net5. Please help me how to do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After the `WebView2` has been initialized.

Do:

```
webView21.CoreWebView2.Settings.AreDevToolsEnabled = false;
```

where 'webView21' is the name of the `WebView2` control.

You can see all settings here: [CoreWebView2Settings Class
Definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2settings?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.664.37)

Comment: Thank you for quick reply it solved my problem

Comment: ```
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeAsync();
        }

        async void InitializeAsync()
        {
            await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null);
            webView.CoreWebView2.Settings.AreDefaultContextMenusEnabled = false;
            webView.CoreWebView2.Settings.AreDevToolsEnabled = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    WebView2.CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted += (sender, args) =>
    {
        if (args.IsSuccess)
        {
            var vw2 = (WebView2)sender;
            vw2!.CoreWebView2.Settings.AreDevToolsEnabled = false;
        }
    };
```