# How to prevent showing source code in WebView2

Tags: webview2

I'm using WebView2 component for a hybrid app, and I've disabled the accelerator keys that show the DevTool window.

Unfortunately there is still the 'CTRL-U' hotkey that shows the source code of the page.

Is there a way to disable it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable Devtools in Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65428492/disable-devtools-in-microsoft-web-webview2-wpf-component)

Comment: Well, it's not what I asked for... `AreDefaultContextMenusEnabled` and `AreDevToolsEnabled` only prevent from opening the DevTools window by the user, but the hot-key `CTRL-U` is still available

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it!

In `CoreWebView2Settings` there is a property `AreBrowserAcceleratorKeysEnabled` that disables all "low level" hotkeys (also DevTools ones).

Just my opinion, but I find these settings counter-intuitive; I mean, I can disable DevTools with the property `AreDevToolsEnabled` (which removes both the entry in the context menu and the relative hotkeys), but yet programmatically invocable, and then there is also the `AreBrowserAcceleratorKeysEnabled` which disables every hotkeys (with the exception to text editing actions), but keeping the entry in the context menu for the DevTools.